# Как изменить стилизацию полосы прокрутки при наведении на ее блок?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Хочу добиться эффекта как в десктопной версии Telegram, т.е. при наведении на блок появлялась полоса прокрутки. Можно ли реализовать такой эффект и как?

```css
.scroll_block{
    height:400px;
    background:red;
    color:#fff;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.scroll_block::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 3px;
    opacity: 0;
}
 
.scroll_block::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: transparent;
 border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.scroll_block::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: transparent; 
}
/* Не работает */
.scroll_block:hover .scroll_block::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: white; 
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll_block">
  <h1>TEST</h1>

  <h1>TEST</h1>

  <h1>TEST</h1>

  <h1>TEST</h1>

  <h1>TEST</h1>

  <h1>TEST</h1>

  <h1>TEST</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ | http://blog.dynamicdrive.com/top-7-custom-scrollbar-javascript-and-jquery-plugins/

Comment: Скролл, большинство инпутов, селект - стандартными средствами css не стилизуются вообще никак, для этого используется js, который заменяет стандартные элементы на дивы (или другие элементы), создавая, таким образом, псевдо-элементы управления. Когда же, наконец станет возможно издеваться над браузером через css (да еще и кроссбраузерно), все верстальщики мира устроят пьянку.